# How to get md-select value from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-material

I have made select menu using angular material with `md-select` tag. Then i tried to get get selected value from jQuery. But it's not working correctly. Here is the code sample.

```
                   <md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState" id="medi">

                            <md-option > a </md-option>
                            <md-option > b </md-option>
                            <md-option > c </md-option>

                    </md-select>

                <md-input-container id="add">
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" >Add</md-button>
                </md-input-container>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#add").click(function (){

        var s=$(" #medi ").val();
        alert(s);
});
});
```

Is it possible to get values from `md-select` tag using jQuery? Any help highly appreciate.

Comment: "But it's not working correctly" Okay what does it show? what about the click event ? what are the expected results? please clarify

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie The alert box showing empty. I want to alert the selected value.

Comment: Why are you getting the value via jQuery? It's in your model already, just use `ctrl.userState`, ie. `<md-button ng-click="ctrl.someFn(ctrl.userState)">`

Comment: @WilliamB I plan use only angular material, because i want get data with jquery. I can get data from input box, but i'm unable to get data from md-select.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='a' ng-model="a">         this is my dom value container
  <md-input-container>
    <label>select</label>
    <md-select ng-model="a">         this is where my value is stored
        <md-option value="1">11</md-option>
        <md-option value="2">22</md-option>
        <md-option value="3">33</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

use jquery to call -> var s=$(" #a").val();
md-select does not create dom element to sore value.
Try binding it to an input dom.

Note: It only works for getting values not setting values.